# Update column with selfreference in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have really primitive job I have to do in Oracle. Let's say I have two tables.

```
T1
+--------+
| NUMBER |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   2    |
|   3    |
|   2    |
|   1    |
+--------+

T2
+------------+------------+
| OLD_NUMBER | NEW_NUMBER |
+------------+------------+
|      1     |     5      |
|      2     |     9      |
|      3     |     17     |
+------------+------------+

T1 after
+--------+
| NUMBER |
+--------+
|   5    |
|   9    |
|   17   |
|   9    |
|   5    |
+--------+
```

I want to update T1 with corresponding numbers in T2. T1 does have duplicates, but both columns in T2 are unique. How the hell I can update T1? I tried multiple updates, updates with where exists clausule, I tried merge, I tried select for update, nothing works. I still get some error either about multiple columns or key-preserved table. Every update I found uses some other columns for joining like ID, but those tables doesn't have anything like that. This is such a simple task and I already spent few hours trying to solve it. I'm starting to get really desperate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
update t1
    set number = (select t2.new_number from t2 where t2.old_number = t1.number)
    where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.old_number = t1.number);
```

Comment: Thank you! No errors and few rows updated, it might work. Care to explain, why there has to be "select 1" in where exists clausule? Every examples I found were basically same selects. I just don't understand, why this query works.

Comment: @TomášMrázek . . . What comes after the `select` in an `exists` doesn't matter.  "1" is easy to type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE T1 i
   SET NUMBER_T =
          (SELECT MAX (NEW_NUMBER)
             FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.NUMBER_T = T2.OLD_NUMBER
            WHERE T2.OLD_NUMBER = i.NUMBER_T);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2c1f/1)

Comment: Thank you. I persented a really simple tables, the real problem is data migration for production database with 10m+ records. I was looking for a solution with join due to expected better performance. Could there be  SELECT DISCTINCT instead of MAX function?